# Unable to fetch Occurrence Data using occ_search function of rgbif package in R

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics

I am trying to get records for `class = Mammalia` from the `rgbif` R package. First, I tried the `usageKey`:

```
key <- name_backbone(name = "Mammalia")
```

which successfully returned the `usageKey`.

Then I tried using `occ_search` and received the following errors:

```
occ_search(taxonKey = key, limit = 20)
```

> Error: Invalid integer range: Mammalia

```
occ_search(taxonKey = key, limit = 10)
```

> Error: Invalid integer range: Mammalia

Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a very minor detail when using the `key`. Note that your variable `key` is a list. To use it as a `taxonKey`, you will need to access it via the `$` operator. Here is what I got:

```
library(rgbif)
key <- name_backbone(name = "Mammalia")
key$usageKey
## [1] 359
```

Alternatively, use the double bracket operator (`[[]]`):

```
key[[1]]
## [1] 359
```

Now, you should have no problem accessing the taxonomy information:

```
occ_search(taxonKey = key$usageKey, limit = 20)

## Records found [10730158] 
## Records returned [20] 
## No. unique hierarchies [3] 
## No. media records [1] 
## No. facets [0] 
## Args [taxonKey=359, limit=20, offset=0, fields=all] 
## # A tibble: 20 × 61
##           name        key decimalLatitude decimalLongitude issues
##          <chr>      <int>           <dbl>            <dbl>  <chr>
## 1    Lynx lynx 1424727732        63.43489         9.950017 gass84
## 2  Canis lupus 1425221384        60.65852        12.068240 gass84
## (more records omitted)
```

Hope this helps.